# Как выровнять структуру XML?

Tags: python, xml

Как выровнять структуру XML текста? 
То есть, имеется XML текст в таком виде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>    <message>        <report>            <station ID="100" Name="main"/>                                                         <parameter VAR=A1>     100      </parameter>            <parameter VAR=A2> 200 </parameter>   </report> </message>
```

Подскажите можно ли ему средствами Питона, придать нормальный вид? 
Примерно такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>    
<message>        
<report>            
<station ID="100" Name="main"/>                                                     
<parameter VAR=A1> 
100      
</parameter>            
<parameter VAR=A2> 
200 
</parameter> 
</report> 
</message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>    <message>        <report> ...'
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_str)
print(doc.toprettyxml())
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206856/1911548)

Comment: Если запустить код в таком же виде как вы представили, то выскакивает ошибка: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 55, ну это и понятно, так как XML сообщение не корректно. Если сделать его корректным, то появляется уже другая ошибка: AttributeError: module 'xml' has no attribute 'toprettyxml' То есть получается нет там такого атрибута?

Comment: Исправил опечатку.

Comment: В принципе, вот так работает: 'import xml.dom.minidom

xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>    <message>        <report> </report> </message>'
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_str)
print(doc.toprettyxml())' , но есть нюанс. устанавливаются пробелы между строк:(

Comment: К примеру вот так:                                                                                                            
`import xmlformatter

doc2 = """здесь наш корявый XML код"""

formatter = xmlformatter.Formatter(indent="1", indent_char="\t", encoding_output="ISO-8859-1", preserve=["literal"])

print(formatter.format_string(doc2).decode('utf-8'))`                                                               
Код получается красивый, но тоже есть минус:( Это то что модуль не стандартный и его приходится подкачивать:(